# Are the English "Woe" and the German "Wo" related?

Tags: english, german, roots

Is the English "Woe" and the German "Wo" related?

I just heard a colleague say, "Wo ist mein ..." and I thought of the band *Woe is me*.

Are these words just false cognates... or is there some common root?

Comment: There are innumerable false cognates like that. Especially when you have short words, the chances of two words whose meanings have superficially nothing to do with each other *actually* having nothing to do with each other are rather high.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Wilson's comment:

The English /oː/[oʊ̯] in indigenous words is derived from a Proto-Germanic diphthong that is reconstructed as pgm. *ai (pgm. *ai > Old English ā > modern /oː/). The same diphthong is the root of German /aɪ̯/(usually spelled ⟨ei⟩) and /eː/ (can be spelled ⟨eh⟩). That's why German *Stein* and English *stone* are cognates as well as *weh* and *woe*.

*Where* and *wo* are not as easy to explain. By also considering Dutch *waar* you can reconstruct a Proto Germanic *hwē¹r > West-Germanic *hwār.
*hwār* must have been palatalized in English. In German a long /aː/ became /o:/ in some dialects. This seems to be a problematic case overall, since there is a short vowel in the Norse cognate. See also https://www.dwds.de/wb/wo

Comment: This explains a lot of cases here English has `o` and German has `e`, as in the OP's question.

Answer (score 3):

They have nothing to do with eachother, except that they kind of sound similar. But consider similar words with similar meanings!

English Woe => German Weh

German Wo => English Where

These two are pairs of words which are historically related.

As to the phrase "*Woe is me*", one German translation could be "*Weh mir*". And in the closely related Yiddish, "vey iz mir" is sometimes heard.